# I keep getting a error:"no operator >> matches thees operands" on variables that are int and bool. In the >> operator overload

Tags: c++, overloading, operands

```
class user
{
private:
    std::string  first_name;
    std::string middle_name;
    std::string  last_name;
     int ID;
     static int next_id;

public:

         static int next_user_id()
        {
        next_id++;
        return next_id;
        }
        group User_Group;   
        void set_ID(int c)
        {
        ID=c;
        }
        int get_ID()
        {
        return ID;
        }
        void set_first_name(std::string c)
        {
            first_name=c;
        }
        string get_first_name()
        {
        return first_name;
        }
        void set_middle_name(std::string c)
        {
            middle_name=c;
        }
        string get_middle_name()
        {
            return middle_name;
        }
        void set_last_name(std::string c)
        {
            last_name=c;
        }
        string get_last_name()
        {
             return last_name;
        }
        user()
        {
            ID = user::next_id++;
        }
friend istream operator>>(istream is, user User);
friend ostream operator<<(ostream os, user User);
};
int user::next_id;
istream operator>>(istream is, user User)
{
    is >> User.get_first_name();
    is >> User.get_middle_name();
    is >> User.get_last_name();
    is >> User.get_ID();
    is >> User.User_Group.get_name();
    for(int j=0;j<=4;j++)
    {
        is >> User.User_Group.Week_Food[j].get_breakfsat();
        is >> User.User_Group.Week_Food[j].get_lunch();
        is >> User.User_Group.Week_Food[j].get_dinner();
    }
    for (int j=0;j<=30;j++) 
    {
        is >> User.User_Group.Month_Food[j].get_breakfsat();
        is >> User.User_Group.Month_Food[j].get_lunch();
        is >> User.User_Group.Month_Food[j].get_dinner();
    }
}


ostream operator<<(ostream os, user User)
{
    os<<User.get_first_name()<<" "<< User.get_middle_name() <<" "<<User.get_last_name()<<" ";
        for(int j=0;j<=4;j++)
        {
        os<<User.User_Group.Week_Food[j].get_breakfsat()<<" "<<User.User_Group.Week_Food[j].get_lunch()<<" "<< User.User_Group.Week_Food[j].get_dinner()<<" ";
        }
        for (int j=0;j<=30;j++) 
        {
        os<< User.User_Group.Month_Food[j].get_breakfsat()<<" "<<User.User_Group.Month_Food[j].get_lunch()<<" "<<User.User_Group.Month_Food[j].get_dinner();
        }
}
```

I'm new to c++ and maybe this is a dumb question but I need to write a array of objects to a file and read it form there by overloading the << and  >> operators. I get the error when i try to use it for members of the class that are int and bool. It seems to work ok for the the string types so I dont know how to proceed.

Comment: `get_breakfsat` is consistently misspelled in your code...

Answer (score 4):

One of the problems is here:

```
is >> User.get_ID();
```

`get_ID()` returns an `int` by value. In order to "stream" a value into the `ID` variable, you would need to return a (non-const) reference to it:

```
class user {
  ....
  int& get_ID() { return ID; }  // non-const version (e.g. for istream)
  const int& get_ID() { return ID; } // const version
  ...
 };
```

Furthermore, you need the operators to take and return references to streams:

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, user User);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, user User);
```

You may also want to avoid copying the `User` objects by passing references:

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, user& User); // modifies user so no const
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const user& User); // should not modify user
```

This would require that you make your getter methods `const`, which you should do anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry but this did not help me and I didnt even understand it

Comment: @user1523627 what did you try and what error are you getting?

Comment: I tried both of your solution the first one did not change the error. The second one adds new error on the User object in the overload functions and the error is:"The object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function".

Comment: @user1523627 what line is the error in when you try the first solution?

Comment: is >> User.get_ID(); and then every line in the for cycles in the overload functions.

Comment: @JoeGauterin in the light of more information, I think the error is that `get_ID()` returns `int`, and OP is attempting to use `istream& operator>>`, which expects a non-const reference, which cannot bind to a temporary.

Comment: @user1523627 good to hear that. Note that you can accept the answer by clicking on the tick by the big number. This helps others see that the question is considered answered, and makes it more likely for you to get answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In you reader function you have lines like this:

```
is >> User.get_first_name();
is >> User.get_middle_name();
is >> User.get_last_name();
is >> User.get_ID();
```

These functions return *lvalues* or values that can be *read from* not something that can be *written to*.  You *could* add overloads of these functions like this:

```
int & get_ID() // Note return of reference to member variable!
{
return ID;
}
```

But then you would have to make the getters that you have now const (which you should do anyway because they query the object - not change it):

```
int get_ID() const // <- note const - meaning this fn doesn't change user.
{
return ID;
}
```

This is because overloads cannot be distinguished by return type only.  making the getters const make the implicit this argument const&.

Having said all that, I would *NOT* add the overloads that return references.  It's bad practice since it exposes your member variables in potentially damaging ways.
I recommend reading from istream into local variables and then using your setters.  That's what they're there for.

```
int myID;
is >> myID;
set_ID(myID);
```

This opens the possibility that:

1. Your setters could do checking in your inputs which are short circuited by reading directly into your class object.
2. You could add a check that there was not an error after your read from the input stream is.

This gives you flexibility.  I've found it is always best to protect yourself against malformed files and databases.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the code fails to compile is that you are reading into a temporary, which the compiler doesn't let you. The point is that the call to `get_ID()` returns a *copy*(!) of the value in the user structure. If you then stored some value in that copy, it would leave the original unmodified anyway. Remember that by default, all parameters passed to functions and returned from functions are copied.

To fix this, instead of using `is >> User.get_ID()` use `is >> User.ID`. I'd do it similarly for output, but there it doesn't matter. You can access these private variables because the `operator>>` and `operator<<` are friend functions.